# Why do I get spurious context menu popup for left click?

Tags: trackpad, contextual-menu

On my MacBook Pro, when using the trackpad, I get spurious context menu popup when I'm trying to do a left click.  It seems related to my other hand holding the laptop as I don't think it occurs ever if I remove the other and only have the one hand clicking.  I turned off secondary click in Trackpad of System Preferences, but that didn't seem to help.

It makes using the trackpad pretty hard, as I often need to click several times to get a left click and not a right click.

Comment: Ctrl-click == right click. Could you be resting on the Ctrl key?

Comment: No modifier keys are being held down.

Comment: Swollen battery squeezing the mobo into the case?